# Why does seaborn choose different colors with the same plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

Why does seaborn choose different hues when using the same code on different slices of data sets?  Is there logic behind the choice?

I have two graphs filtered on a different slice of the data.  The slices and graph code are the same.  But the colors between the two are different.  Does anyone know why?

Below is the code and plot for plot 1.

```
exp = factors[(factors['Variable'] == 'unit_drv_exp_model') & (factors['Cover'] == 'BI')]

factors_ordered = CategoricalDtype(categories = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

exp['level_ordered'] = exp['Level'].astype(factors_ordered)

model_4_mean = exp[exp['model'] == 'model_4']['Interaction_Factor'].mean()
model_5_mean = exp[exp['model'] == 'model_5']['Interaction_Factor'].mean()
actual_mean = exp[exp['model'] == 'actual']['Interaction_Factor'].mean()
normalizing_factor_4 = model_4_mean/model_5_mean
normalizing_factor_A = actual_mean/model_5_mean

def normalize(row):
    if row['model'] == 'actual':
        val = row['Interaction_Factor']/normalizing_factor_A

    elif row['model'] == 'model_4':
        val = row['Interaction_Factor']/normalizing_factor_4

    elif row['model'] == 'model_5':
        val = row['Interaction_Factor']

    else:
        val = row['Interaction_Factor']

    return val

exp['normal_factor'] = exp.apply(normalize, axis = 1)

print("model_4 mean: " , multi_unit[multi_unit['model'] == 'model_4']['normal_factor'].mean()
      ,"model_5_mean: " , multi_unit[multi_unit['model'] == 'model_5']['normal_factor'].mean()
      ,"actual_mean: " , multi_unit[multi_unit['model'] == 'actual']['normal_factor'].mean())

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,5]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
ax = plt.figure(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
#ax = sns.lineplot(x ='level_ordered', y = 'normal_factor', data = exp, hue = 'model')
ax = sns.pointplot(x ='level_ordered', y = 'normal_factor', data = exp, hue = 'model')
ax = plt.title('Motorcycle Variable Comparison BI')
ax = plt.ylabel('factor')
ax = plt.xlabel('Driver Experience')
ax = plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize = 8)
```

[image]

Below is the code and pic for plot 2. As you can see, the code (aside from the filter) is the same but chooses to assign hue colors to different values.

```
    exp = factors[(factors['Variable'] == 'unit_drv_exp_model') & (factors['Cover'] == 'PD')]

    factors_ordered = CategoricalDtype(categories = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

    exp['level_ordered'] = exp['Level'].astype(factors_ordered)

    model_4_mean = exp[exp['model'] == 'model_4']['Interaction_Factor'].mean()
    model_5_mean = exp[exp['model'] == 'model_5']['Interaction_Factor'].mean()
    actual_mean = exp[exp['model'] == 'actual']['Interaction_Factor'].mean()
    normalizing_factor_4 = model_4_mean/model_5_mean
    normalizing_factor_A = actual_mean/model_5_mean

    def normalize(row):
        if row['model'] == 'actual':
            val = row['Interaction_Factor']/normalizing_factor_A

        elif row['model'] == 'model_4':
            val = row['Interaction_Factor']/normalizing_factor_4

        elif row['model'] == 'model_5':
            val = row['Interaction_Factor']

    else:
        val = row['Interaction_Factor']

    return val

exp['normal_factor'] = exp.apply(normalize, axis = 1)

print("model_4 mean: " , multi_unit[multi_unit['model'] == 'model_4']['normal_factor'].mean()
      ,"model_5_mean: " , multi_unit[multi_unit['model'] == 'model_5']['normal_factor'].mean()
      ,"actual_mean: " , multi_unit[multi_unit['model'] == 'actual']['normal_factor'].mean())

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,5]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
ax = plt.figure(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
#ax = sns.lineplot(x ='level_ordered', y = 'normal_factor', data = exp, hue = 'model')
ax = sns.pointplot(x ='level_ordered', y = 'normal_factor', data = exp, hue = 'model')
ax = plt.title('Motorcycle Variable Comparison PD')
ax = plt.ylabel('factor')
ax = plt.xlabel('Driver Experience')
ax = plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize = 8)
```

[image]

Comment: If you want a specific order of hues, use `hue_order` argument. Else, the order is determined by what comes first in the dataframe.

Comment: Can you shrink that down to a minimal running example? I tried to diff the two code pages but unfortunately the indentation is different.